# How to color scatterplot based on the values of y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Hello everyone I made a scatter plot based on two lists. Now I want to color the scatter plot based on the y-axis value. For example, if the value on the y-axis is greater than 30000 I want to color it red and rest all values blue? What's the best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Numpy's ndarrays, it's simpler

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# test data
y = np.random.randint(2800, 3100, size=(100,))
x = np.arange(0, 100)

# create a Boolean array (a mask), possibly negate it using the "~" unary operator
ygt3000 = y>3000
plt.scatter(x[~ygt3000], y[~ygt3000], color='blue')
plt.scatter(x[ygt3000], y[ygt3000], color='red')
```

if you are using ***real*** lists, it's a bit more complicated, but can be done using list comprehensions

```py
x = x.tolist()
y = y.tolist()

ygt3000 = [val>3000 for val in y]
plt.scatter([xv for xv, ygt in zip(x, ygt3000) if not ygt],
            [yv for yv, ygt in zip(y, ygt3000) if not ygt], color='blue') 
plt.scatter([xv for xv, ygt in zip(x, ygt3000) if ygt],
            [yv for yv, ygt in zip(y, ygt3000) if ygt], color='red')
```

Here it is the result of the code above when applied to two sequences of random numbers.

[image]

---

August 2021, because Trenton McKinney made a beautiful edit (thank you Trenton) this post came again to my attention, and I saw the light

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=['r' if v>3000 else 'b' for v in y])
```

---

Just a day later, I realized that a  similar feat can be used with Numpy, taking advantage of *advanced indexing*

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=np.array(('b','r'))[(y>3000).astype(int)])
```

but honestly I prefer the two-pass approach I've used previously, because it's more to the point and conveys much more meaning. Or, in other words, the latter looks obfuscated code...

Comment: Thankyou so much @gboffi this was exactly what I was looking for for the last two days. I was using actual lists and could not find any solution on internet. Again I am grateful to you.